# Issue with replication when upgrading Mongodb 4.4.8 to 6.0.4

Tags: mongodb, docker, replicaset

We have a replica set with three nodes in the docker container hosted on three hosts on a 128 GB filesystem supporting each mongodb data nodes.

Every mongodb container have 5GB of memory limits and 1,5 CPU limits, mongodb wiredTiger cacheSizeGB is define to  2.5.

The upgrade process followed is that of the documentation provided here:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/5.0-upgrade-replica-set/
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/6.0-upgrade-replica-set/

After investigation in the logs of the different versions I see that this error is present in version 4.4.8 and 5.0 :

```
{"log":"{\"t\":{\"$date\":\"2023-03-04T16:22:54.348+00:00\"},\"s\":\"I\",  \"c\":\"COMMAND\",  \"id\":51803,   \"ctx\":\"conn125400\",\"msg\":\"Slow query\",\"attr\":{\"type\":\"command\",\"ns\":\"local.oplog.rs\",\"command\":{\"find\":\"oplog.rs\",\"filter\":{},\"sort\":{\"-$natural\":1},\"lsid\":{\"id\":{\"$uuid\":\"9a02cb13-57ee-4793-a27d-ae51ef6774af\"}},\"$clusterTime\":{\"clusterTime\":{\"$timestamp\":{\"t\":1677946973,\"i\":2}},\"signature\":{\"hash\":{\"$binary\":{\"base64\":\"EBMoYzvf/BJE1tf1ghz6ZkQ+E2Y=\",\"subType\":\"0\"}},\"keyId\":7206450133318238212}},\"$db\":\"local\",\"$readPreference\":{\"mode\":\"primaryPreferred\"}},\"planSummary\":\"COLLSCAN\",\"numYields\":71,\"queryHash\":\"A11B6D23\",\"planCacheKey\":\"A11B6D23\",\"ok\":0,\"errMsg\":\"Executor error during find command :: caused by :: Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting.\",\"errName\":\"QueryExceededMemoryLimitNoDiskUseAllowed\",\"errCode\":292,\"reslen\":378,\"locks\":{\"ReplicationStateTransition\":{\"acquireCount\":{\"w\":72}},\"Global\":{\"acquireCount\":{\"r\":72}},\"Database\":{\"acquireCount\":{\"r\":72}},\"Mutex\":{\"acquireCount\":{\"r\":1}},\"oplog\":{\"acquireCount\":{\"r\":72}}},\"storage\":{},\"protocol\":\"op_msg\",\"durationMillis\":105}}\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2023-03-04T16:22:54.349177116Z"}
```

this error refers to the command : "command":{"find":"oplog.rs","filter":{},"sort":{"-$natural":1}

It fails because the result is too large to be stored in memory and writing to disk is disabled by default in version 4.4.8 and 5.0 which is different from version 6.0
In my case it's exactly this command which causes the filling of my disk in version 6.0.
I do not understand which event causes the execution of this command.

I suppose this event is due to out of sync of the replication or election process which causes the OPLOG reading for data recovering on every node, but this process is it a normal process of mongodb?

Must I set up a specific configuration for this process to run normally without having to serialize on disk?
Is it possible to restrict the size of temporary files written to the drive by Mongo?
Is my mongodb cluster wrongly sized ?

We have restarted the migration process from 4.4.8 to 6.0.4 and we have always the same issue.

Here is the output of the rs.status() command for each version

Version 4.4.8

```
rs.status()
{
    "set" : "ds-rs",
    "date" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:28:31.952Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "term" : NumberLong(3),
    "syncSourceHost" : "",
    "syncSourceId" : -1,
    "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
    "majorityVoteCount" : 2,
    "writeMajorityCount" : 2,
    "votingMembersCount" : 3,
    "writableVotingMembersCount" : 3,
    "optimes" : {
        "lastCommittedOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1677961707, 41),
            "t" : NumberLong(3)
        },
        "lastCommittedWallTime" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:28:27.492Z"),
        "readConcernMajorityOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1677961707, 41),
            "t" : NumberLong(3)
        },
        "readConcernMajorityWallTime" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:28:27.492Z"),
        "appliedOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1677961707, 41),
            "t" : NumberLong(3)
        },
        "durableOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1677961707, 41),
            "t" : NumberLong(3)
        },
        "lastAppliedWallTime" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:28:27.492Z"),
        "lastDurableWallTime" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:28:27.492Z")
    },
    "lastStableRecoveryTimestamp" : Timestamp(1677961703, 1),
    "electionCandidateMetrics" : {
        "lastElectionReason" : "electionTimeout",
        "lastElectionDate" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:23:43.468Z"),
        "electionTerm" : NumberLong(3),
        "lastCommittedOpTimeAtElection" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
            "t" : NumberLong(-1)
        },
        "lastSeenOpTimeAtElection" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1677959280, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(2)
        },
        "numVotesNeeded" : 2,
        "priorityAtElection" : 1,
        "electionTimeoutMillis" : NumberLong(10000),
        "numCatchUpOps" : NumberLong(0),
        "newTermStartDate" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:23:43.564Z"),
        "wMajorityWriteAvailabilityDate" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:23:44.805Z")
    },
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "11.0.50.9:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 290,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1677961707, 41),
                "t" : NumberLong(3)
            },
            "optimeDurable" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1677961707, 41),
                "t" : NumberLong(3)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:28:27Z"),
            "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:28:27Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:28:31.779Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:28:31.022Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
            "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "",
            "syncSourceHost" : "11.0.50.11:27017",
            "syncSourceId" : 3,
            "infoMessage" : "",
            "configVersion" : 1,
            "configTerm" : 3
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "name" : "11.0.50.10:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 298,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1677961707, 41),
                "t" : NumberLong(3)
            },
            "optimeDurable" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1677961707, 41),
                "t" : NumberLong(3)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:28:27Z"),
            "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:28:27Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:28:31.781Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:28:30.026Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
            "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "",
            "syncSourceHost" : "11.0.50.9:27017",
            "syncSourceId" : 1,
            "infoMessage" : "",
            "configVersion" : 1,
            "configTerm" : 3
        },
        {
            "_id" : 3,
            "name" : "11.0.50.11:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 311,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1677961707, 41),
                "t" : NumberLong(3)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:28:27Z"),
            "syncSourceHost" : "",
            "syncSourceId" : -1,
            "infoMessage" : "",
            "electionTime" : Timestamp(1677961423, 1),
            "electionDate" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:23:43Z"),
            "configVersion" : 1,
            "configTerm" : 3,
            "self" : true,
            "lastHeartbeatMessage" : ""
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1,
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1677961707, 41),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"p7TYQ+teX1adsMmdcQUirXqfXIE="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong("7206450133318238212")
        }
    },
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1677961707, 41)
}
```

Version 5.0

```
rs.status()
{
    "set" : "ds-rs",
    "date" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:35:46.296Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "term" : NumberLong(4),
    "syncSourceHost" : "",
    "syncSourceId" : -1,
    "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
    "majorityVoteCount" : 2,
    "writeMajorityCount" : 2,
    "votingMembersCount" : 3,
    "writableVotingMembersCount" : 3,
    "optimes" : {
        "lastCommittedOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1677962136, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(4)
        },
        "lastCommittedWallTime" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:35:36.996Z"),
        "readConcernMajorityOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1677962136, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(4)
        },
        "appliedOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1677962136, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(4)
        },
        "durableOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1677962136, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(4)
        },
        "lastAppliedWallTime" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:35:36.996Z"),
        "lastDurableWallTime" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:35:36.996Z")
    },
    "lastStableRecoveryTimestamp" : Timestamp(1677962126, 1),
    "electionCandidateMetrics" : {
        "lastElectionReason" : "electionTimeout",
        "lastElectionDate" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:34:56.969Z"),
        "electionTerm" : NumberLong(4),
        "lastCommittedOpTimeAtElection" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
            "t" : NumberLong(-1)
        },
        "lastSeenOpTimeAtElection" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1677961933, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(3)
        },
        "numVotesNeeded" : 2,
        "priorityAtElection" : 1,
        "electionTimeoutMillis" : NumberLong(10000),
        "numCatchUpOps" : NumberLong(0),
        "newTermStartDate" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:34:56.991Z"),
        "wMajorityWriteAvailabilityDate" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:34:57.032Z")
    },
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "11.0.50.9:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 47,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1677962136, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(4)
            },
            "optimeDurable" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1677962136, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(4)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:35:36Z"),
            "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:35:36Z"),
            "lastAppliedWallTime" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:35:36.996Z"),
            "lastDurableWallTime" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:35:36.996Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:35:45.018Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:35:44.896Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
            "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "",
            "syncSourceHost" : "11.0.50.11:27017",
            "syncSourceId" : 3,
            "infoMessage" : "",
            "configVersion" : 1,
            "configTerm" : 4
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "name" : "11.0.50.10:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 58,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1677962136, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(4)
            },
            "optimeDurable" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1677962136, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(4)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:35:36Z"),
            "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:35:36Z"),
            "lastAppliedWallTime" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:35:36.996Z"),
            "lastDurableWallTime" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:35:36.996Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:35:45.029Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:35:45.559Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
            "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "",
            "syncSourceHost" : "11.0.50.11:27017",
            "syncSourceId" : 3,
            "infoMessage" : "",
            "configVersion" : 1,
            "configTerm" : 4
        },
        {
            "_id" : 3,
            "name" : "11.0.50.11:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 76,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1677962136, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(4)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:35:36Z"),
            "lastAppliedWallTime" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:35:36.996Z"),
            "lastDurableWallTime" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:35:36.996Z"),
            "syncSourceHost" : "",
            "syncSourceId" : -1,
            "infoMessage" : "",
            "electionTime" : Timestamp(1677962096, 1),
            "electionDate" : ISODate("2023-03-04T20:34:56Z"),
            "configVersion" : 1,
            "configTerm" : 4,
            "self" : true,
            "lastHeartbeatMessage" : ""
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1,
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1677962136, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"4zdWQKCg1WIw8twSfdxRx49MlsU="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong("7206450133318238212")
        }
    },
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1677962136, 1)
}
```

Version 6.0.4 Before Before setting FeatureCompatibilityVersion "6.0

```
rs.status()
{
  set: 'ds-rs',
  date: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:41:13.192Z"),
  myState: 1,
  term: Long("5"),
  syncSourceHost: '',
  syncSourceId: -1,
  heartbeatIntervalMillis: Long("2000"),
  majorityVoteCount: 2,
  writeMajorityCount: 2,
  votingMembersCount: 3,
  writableVotingMembersCount: 3,
  optimes: {
    lastCommittedOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1677962471, i: 1 }), t: Long("5") },
    lastCommittedWallTime: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:41:11.565Z"),
    readConcernMajorityOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1677962471, i: 1 }), t: Long("5") },
    appliedOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1677962471, i: 1 }), t: Long("5") },
    durableOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1677962471, i: 1 }), t: Long("5") },
    lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:41:11.565Z"),
    lastDurableWallTime: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:41:11.565Z")
  },
  lastStableRecoveryTimestamp: Timestamp({ t: 1677962337, i: 1 }),
  electionCandidateMetrics: {
    lastElectionReason: 'electionTimeout',
    lastElectionDate: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:40:50.481Z"),
    electionTerm: Long("5"),
    lastCommittedOpTimeAtElection: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 0, i: 0 }), t: Long("-1") },
    lastSeenOpTimeAtElection: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1677962347, i: 1 }), t: Long("4") },
    numVotesNeeded: 2,
    priorityAtElection: 1,
    electionTimeoutMillis: Long("10000"),
    numCatchUpOps: Long("0"),
    newTermStartDate: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:40:51.551Z"),
    wMajorityWriteAvailabilityDate: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:40:56.028Z")
  },
  members: [
    {
      _id: 1,
      name: '11.0.50.9:27017',
      health: 1,
      state: 2,
      stateStr: 'SECONDARY',
      uptime: 11,
      optime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1677962471, i: 1 }), t: Long("5") },
      optimeDurable: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1677962471, i: 1 }), t: Long("5") },
      optimeDate: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:41:11.000Z"),
      optimeDurableDate: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:41:11.000Z"),
      lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:41:11.565Z"),
      lastDurableWallTime: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:41:11.565Z"),
      lastHeartbeat: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:41:11.593Z"),
      lastHeartbeatRecv: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:41:11.896Z"),
      pingMs: Long("3"),
      lastHeartbeatMessage: '',
      syncSourceHost: '11.0.50.11:27017',
      syncSourceId: 3,
      infoMessage: '',
      configVersion: 2,
      configTerm: 5
    },
    {
      _id: 2,
      name: '11.0.50.10:27017',
      health: 1,
      state: 2,
      stateStr: 'SECONDARY',
      uptime: 22,
      optime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1677962471, i: 1 }), t: Long("5") },
      optimeDurable: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1677962471, i: 1 }), t: Long("5") },
      optimeDate: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:41:11.000Z"),
      optimeDurableDate: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:41:11.000Z"),
      lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:41:11.565Z"),
      lastDurableWallTime: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:41:11.565Z"),
      lastHeartbeat: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:41:11.574Z"),
      lastHeartbeatRecv: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:41:11.586Z"),
      pingMs: Long("1"),
      lastHeartbeatMessage: '',
      syncSourceHost: '11.0.50.11:27017',
      syncSourceId: 3,
      infoMessage: '',
      configVersion: 2,
      configTerm: 5
    },
    {
      _id: 3,
      name: '11.0.50.11:27017',
      health: 1,
      state: 1,
      stateStr: 'PRIMARY',
      uptime: 38,
      optime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1677962471, i: 1 }), t: Long("5") },
      optimeDate: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:41:11.000Z"),
      lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:41:11.565Z"),
      lastDurableWallTime: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:41:11.565Z"),
      syncSourceHost: '',
      syncSourceId: -1,
      infoMessage: '',
      electionTime: Timestamp({ t: 1677962450, i: 1 }),
      electionDate: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:40:50.000Z"),
      configVersion: 2,
      configTerm: 5,
      self: true,
      lastHeartbeatMessage: ''
    }
  ],
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp({ t: 1677962471, i: 1 }),
    signature: {
      hash: Binary(Buffer.from("a93b92c3b1b03f506d12a906e8b1b2aa853d7ccc", "hex"), 0),
      keyId: Long("7206450133318238212")
    }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp({ t: 1677962471, i: 1 })
}
```

Version 6.0.4 After setting FeatureCompatibilityVersion "6.0

```
rs.status()
{
  set: 'ds-rs',
  date: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:42:30.793Z"),
  myState: 1,
  term: Long("5"),
  syncSourceHost: '',
  syncSourceId: -1,
  heartbeatIntervalMillis: Long("2000"),
  majorityVoteCount: 2,
  writeMajorityCount: 2,
  votingMembersCount: 3,
  writableVotingMembersCount: 3,
  optimes: {
    lastCommittedOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1677962538, i: 4 }), t: Long("5") },
    lastCommittedWallTime: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:42:18.702Z"),
    readConcernMajorityOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1677962538, i: 4 }), t: Long("5") },
    appliedOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1677962538, i: 4 }), t: Long("5") },
    durableOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1677962538, i: 4 }), t: Long("5") },
    lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:42:18.702Z"),
    lastDurableWallTime: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:42:18.702Z")
  },
  lastStableRecoveryTimestamp: Timestamp({ t: 1677962491, i: 1 }),
  electionCandidateMetrics: {
    lastElectionReason: 'electionTimeout',
    lastElectionDate: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:40:50.481Z"),
    electionTerm: Long("5"),
    lastCommittedOpTimeAtElection: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 0, i: 0 }), t: Long("-1") },
    lastSeenOpTimeAtElection: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1677962347, i: 1 }), t: Long("4") },
    numVotesNeeded: 2,
    priorityAtElection: 1,
    electionTimeoutMillis: Long("10000"),
    numCatchUpOps: Long("0"),
    newTermStartDate: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:40:51.551Z"),
    wMajorityWriteAvailabilityDate: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:40:56.028Z")
  },
  members: [
    {
      _id: 1,
      name: '11.0.50.9:27017',
      health: 1,
      state: 2,
      stateStr: 'SECONDARY',
      uptime: 89,
      optime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1677962538, i: 4 }), t: Long("5") },
      optimeDurable: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1677962538, i: 4 }), t: Long("5") },
      optimeDate: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:42:18.000Z"),
      optimeDurableDate: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:42:18.000Z"),
      lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:42:18.702Z"),
      lastDurableWallTime: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:42:18.702Z"),
      lastHeartbeat: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:42:29.673Z"),
      lastHeartbeatRecv: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:42:29.985Z"),
      pingMs: Long("0"),
      lastHeartbeatMessage: '',
      syncSourceHost: '11.0.50.11:27017',
      syncSourceId: 3,
      infoMessage: '',
      configVersion: 2,
      configTerm: 5
    },
    {
      _id: 2,
      name: '11.0.50.10:27017',
      health: 1,
      state: 2,
      stateStr: 'SECONDARY',
      uptime: 100,
      optime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1677962538, i: 4 }), t: Long("5") },
      optimeDurable: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1677962538, i: 4 }), t: Long("5") },
      optimeDate: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:42:18.000Z"),
      optimeDurableDate: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:42:18.000Z"),
      lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:42:18.702Z"),
      lastDurableWallTime: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:42:18.702Z"),
      lastHeartbeat: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:42:29.674Z"),
      lastHeartbeatRecv: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:42:29.675Z"),
      pingMs: Long("1"),
      lastHeartbeatMessage: '',
      syncSourceHost: '11.0.50.11:27017',
      syncSourceId: 3,
      infoMessage: '',
      configVersion: 2,
      configTerm: 5
    },
    {
      _id: 3,
      name: '11.0.50.11:27017',
      health: 1,
      state: 1,
      stateStr: 'PRIMARY',
      uptime: 115,
      optime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1677962538, i: 4 }), t: Long("5") },
      optimeDate: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:42:18.000Z"),
      lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:42:18.702Z"),
      lastDurableWallTime: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:42:18.702Z"),
      syncSourceHost: '',
      syncSourceId: -1,
      infoMessage: '',
      electionTime: Timestamp({ t: 1677962450, i: 1 }),
      electionDate: ISODate("2023-03-04T20:40:50.000Z"),
      configVersion: 2,
      configTerm: 5,
      self: true,
      lastHeartbeatMessage: ''
    }
  ],
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp({ t: 1677962538, i: 4 }),
    signature: {
      hash: Binary(Buffer.from("13338366b839f370e3acf785eb93e20276953006", "hex"), 0),
      keyId: Long("7206450133318238212")
    }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp({ t: 1677962538, i: 4 })
}
```

Here is the output of the rs.printReplicationInfo() command for each version

Version 4.4.8

```
rs.printReplicationInfo()
configured oplog size:   6481.01123046875MB
log length start to end: 77846secs (21.62hrs)
oplog first event time:  Fri Mar 03 2023 22:48:47 GMT+0000 (UTC)
oplog last event time:   Sat Mar 04 2023 20:26:13 GMT+0000 (UTC)
now:                     Sat Mar 04 2023 20:26:17 GMT+0000 (UTC)
```

Version 5.0

```
rs.printReplicationInfo()
configured oplog size:   6481.01123046875MB
log length start to end: 78370secs (21.77hrs)
oplog first event time:  Fri Mar 03 2023 22:48:47 GMT+0000 (UTC)
oplog last event time:   Sat Mar 04 2023 20:34:57 GMT+0000 (UTC)
now:                     Sat Mar 04 2023 20:35:14 GMT+0000 (UTC)
```

Version 6.0.4 After setting FeatureCompatibilityVersion "6.0

```
rs.printReplicationInfo()
actual oplog size
'6481.01123046875 MB'
---
configured oplog size
'6481.01123046875 MB'
---
log length start to end
'78843.99999809265 secs (21.9 hrs)'
---
oplog first event time
'Fri Mar 03 2023 22:48:47 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)'
---
oplog last event time
'Sat Mar 04 2023 20:42:51 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)'
---
now
'Sat Mar 04 2023 20:43:00 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)'
```

Here is the output of the rs.conf() command for version 4.4.8

```
rs.conf()
{
        "_id" : "ds-rs",
        "version" : 1,
        "term" : 1,
        "protocolVersion" : NumberLong(1),
        "writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault" : true,
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "host" : "11.0.50.9:27017",
                        "arbiterOnly" : false,
                        "buildIndexes" : true,
                        "hidden" : false,
                        "priority" : 1,
                        "tags" : {

                        },
                        "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
                        "votes" : 1
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "host" : "11.0.50.10:27017",
                        "arbiterOnly" : false,
                        "buildIndexes" : true,
                        "hidden" : false,
                        "priority" : 1,
                        "tags" : {

                        },
                        "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
                        "votes" : 1
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 3,
                        "host" : "11.0.50.11:27017",
                        "arbiterOnly" : false,
                        "buildIndexes" : true,
                        "hidden" : false,
                        "priority" : 1,
                        "tags" : {

                        },
                        "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
                        "votes" : 1
                }
        ],
        "settings" : {
                "chainingAllowed" : true,
                "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : 2000,
                "heartbeatTimeoutSecs" : 10,
                "electionTimeoutMillis" : 10000,
                "catchUpTimeoutMillis" : -1,
                "catchUpTakeoverDelayMillis" : 30000,
                "getLastErrorModes" : {

                },
                "getLastErrorDefaults" : {
                        "w" : 1,
                        "wtimeout" : 0
                },
                "replicaSetId" : ObjectId("6403ba5704b0564c053d341b")
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, these requests were due to my monitoring solution metricbeat and its module mongodb, more precisely the module replstatus.

https://github.com/elastic/beats/blob/main/metricbeat/module/mongodb/replstatus/info.go

https://github.com/elastic/beats/issues/33616

to solve this problem disable replstatus module in mongodb metricbeat modules